# Replace IDs inside array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [uris] => Array
            (
                [1] => /
                [2] => /news/
                [3] => /about/
                [4] => /contact/
            )

        [templates] => Array
            (
                [1] => 1
                [2] => 2
                [3] => 3
                [4] => 4
            )
    )
```

)

and I need to update all the IDs with a new set of values so the final output should be something like:

```
        [uris] => Array
            (
                [100] => /
                [101] => /news/
                [102] => /about/
                [103] => /contact/
            )

        [templates] => Array
            (
                [100] => 1
                [101] => 2
                [102] => 3
                [103] => 4
            )
```

I think I might need to use a regex pattern like `'/(\[.*?\])/'` but I'm not sure how to put it together to get the final updated output.

**EDIT:** I should mention that the IDs I'm updating to won't be in sequential order, they're coming from a database table of entries in a CMS. Entries are being duplicated so they'll have the same URIs but the second set with have a higher set of IDs than the original ones.

There won't be a rule for the second set of IDs. The only guarantee is that the second set will all be higher than the highest ID from the first set.

The CMS I'm working with allows me to duplicate entries for use on a second site. But the CMS also uses a third party module that creates a serialized array like I've posted above which matches URIs against templates. The module doesn't create a new serialized array of the new entry IDs when the entries get duplicated, so what's I'm trying to do manually.

I thought I could unserialize the array, update the string's old IDs with the corresponding IDs of the new entries, reserialize it, and then copy it back into the database.

Comment: use foreach loop to update what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question update; not too sure what you're trying to do, but I have two guesses.

`arr2d_replace_id` will take all the `uris` and increase key and also a new set of array with updated keys and it's value.

`arr2d_replace_id2` will 1) flip array of templates - where I'm guessing the value represents the ID of route in `uris` and so flipped to preserve values; 2) increase key value on `uris`; 3) change flipped array's value according to the key based on `uris`; 4) flip the array back with the new set info and assign to result.

```
function arr2d_replace_id($arr, $inc) {
    $result = array();

    foreach ($arr['uris'] as $k=>$v) {
        $result['uris'][intval($k) + $inc] = $v;
        $result['templates'][intval($k) + $inc] = $arr['templates'][$k];
    }

    return $result;
}

function arr2d_replace_id2($arr, $inc) {
    $result = array();
    $tpl_flipped = array_flip($arr['templates']);

    foreach ($arr['uris'] as $k=>$v) {
        $result['uris'][intval($k) + $inc] = $v;
        $tpl_flipped[$k] = intval($k) + $inc;
    }

    $result['templates'] = array_flip($tpl_flipped);

    return $result;
}

$test = array(
    'uris' => array(
        1 => '/', '/news/', '/about/', '/contact/',
    ),
    'templates' => array(
        1 => 1, 2, 3, 4
    )
);



print_r( $test );

print_r( arr2d_replace_id($test, 100) );

print_r( arr2d_replace_id2($test, 100) );
```

See in action: http://3v4l.org/T6hHD

Comment: I've made an edit to the question regarding the second set of IDs.

Comment: I've edited my answer, is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 3):

```
Array (
    [1] => /
    [2] => /news/
    [3] => /about/
    [4] => /contact/
)
```

Given this kind of array, what you need to do to replace the keys is simply:

```
$array = array_combine(range(100, 100 + (count($array) - 1)), $array);
```

It generates keys `[100, .., 103]` and splices them into the array.

Comment: I've updated my question. New IDs won't necessarily be in sequential order or start with 100.

Comment: Then be clear about what the rule is or what you need to do. I've shown a general example of how you can replace array keys with another set of keys. Beyond this it's unclear what  your question and/or requirements are or what the problem in implementing it is.

Comment: I've edited the question again to provide more context. Hopefully it gives a clearer idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Still not enough information to write any concrete code for. What is your blocker in implementing whatever you're trying to implement there exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You might have to loop and then replace the keys :

```
foreach ($yourArray as $array) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array['uris']); $i++) {
        $array['uris'][$i][$newkey] = $array['uris'][$i][$oldkey];
        unset($array['uris'][$i][$oldkey]);
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array['templates']); $i++) {
        $array['templates'][$i][$newkey] = $array['templates'][$i][$oldkey];
        unset($array['templates'][$i][$oldkey]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do `$newkey` and `$oldkey` come from?

Answer (score 1):

If the array values are unique, you can use `array_flip`:

```
$array = [
    1 => '/',
    2 => '/contact/',
    3 => '/about/'
];

$counter = 100;
$array = array_flip($array);

$array = array_map(function($oldKey) use (&$counter) {
    return ++$counter;
}, $array);

$array = array_flip($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$mainArray = array();
    $mainArray[]=array("uris" => array("/", '/news', '/about', '/contact') , "templates" => array(1,2,3,4));
    foreach ($mainArray as &$array) {
        $uris = $array['uris'];
        $keys = array_keys($uris);
        for($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++)
        {
            $uris[$keys[$i] + 100]=$uris[$i];
            unset($uris[$i]);
        }

        $template = $array['templates'];
        $keys = array_keys($uris);
        for($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++)
        {
            $template[$keys[$i] + 100]=$template[$i];
            unset($template[$i]);
        }
        $array['uris'] = $uris;
        $array['templates'] = $template;
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($mainArray);
    exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
$array = array(
    array('uris' => array(
                '1' => '/',
                '2' => '/news/',
                '3' => '/about/',
                '4' => '/contact/'
            ),
        'templates' => array
            (
                '1' => '1',
                '2' => '2',
                '3' => '3',
                '4' => '4'
            )
    )
);
$val = 100;
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
            $result[$key][$key1][$val] = $value2;
            $val++;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I've made an edit to the question regarding the second set of IDs.

Comment: ok. Replace "(int)$key2+100" into dynamic or what you need. Simple!